# Start Play! framework app on several ports

Tags: playframework

How can I run play! app on several ports?
I mean, I have a project and I want to run it , for example on port **9000** and on port **9001** at the same time.

If I try to do somthing like : `(PATH_TO_APP)>play "run 9000"` and then in another cmd window `(PATH_TO_APP)>play "run 9001"`
my 1st app will run, but in 2nd case I get :

```
(PATH_TO_APP)\logs\application.log is not a directory so descendants can not be called on itis not a directory
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**But!** If I copy my app to another folder, for example (PATH_TO_APP1) then all will be OK, and play! run both apps:
`(PATH_TO_APP)>play "run 9000"`
`(PATH_TO_APP1)>play "run 9001"`
- OK

Comment: as ___applicius___ wrote you need to use separate folders, if you need it i.e. for stopless redeploy, use i.e. Jenkins for temporary creating the folder and copying the files there

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. On production environment, you can benefit from having an HTTP frontend (Apache, Nginx, Varnish), that could accept connection on several ports, and also manage virtual hosting.

For local/dev env, I don't see how this could be useful?